# Is it possible that resizing an std::vector reduces its capacity?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

I have this container: std::vector< std::tuple,std::vector > > rvec1 
where each inner vector contains a number of elements.
After some computations I resize the inner vectors.
The problem is that when I measure the capacity of each vector it seems that it decreases. 
Is this normal to happen?

Here is the function where I resize the vectors:

```
int merge_vector_elements(std::vector< std::tuple<std::vector<int>,std::vector<float> > >& rvec1){

        long totalCapacity = 0;
        for(auto itr : rvec1){
          totalCapacity += std::get<0>(itr).capacity();
          totalCapacity += std::get<1>(itr).capacity();
        }
        std::cout<<"Total Capacity before merge / shrink: "<<totalCapacity<<std::endl;

        int nnz = 0;
        for (msize_t i=0; i<rvec1.size(); i++){
          int count = 0;
           for(msize_t j = 0; j < std::get<0>(rvec1[i]).size(); ++j, ++count){
             std::get<0>(rvec1[i])[count] = std::get<0>(rvec1[i])[j];
             std::get<1>(rvec1[i])[count] = std::get<1>(rvec1[i])[j];
             while((j+1 != std::get<0>(rvec1[i]).size()) && std::get<0>(rvec1[i])[count] == std::get<0>(rvec1[i])[j+1]){  
               std::get<1>(rvec1[i])[count] += std::get<1>(rvec1[i])[j+1];
               j++;
             } 
           }
           std::get<0>(rvec1[i]).resize(count);
           //std::get<0>(rvec1[i]).shrink_to_fit();
           std::get<1>(rvec1[i]).resize(count);
           //std::get<1>(rvec1[i]).shrink_to_fit();
           nnz += count;
        }
        totalCapacity = 0;
        for(auto itr : rvec1){
          totalCapacity += std::get<0>(itr).capacity();
          totalCapacity += std::get<1>(itr).capacity();
        }
        std::cout<<"Total Capacity after merge / shrink: "<<totalCapacity<<std::endl;

        return nnz;
      }
```

The results are:

Total Capacity before merge / shrink: 254396100

Total Capacity after merge / shrink: 107010297

So the capacity seems to be affected.

Also some sample code where the resize doesn't affect the capacity of the vector.

```
int main(){

  long bufferSize = 1000000000;

  std::vector<double> newVec(bufferSize);

  for(int i=0; i<bufferSize; i++){
      newVec[i] = i * 8.99;
  }

  std::cout<<"Capacity before resize: "<<newVec.capacity()<<std::endl;
  newVec.resize(bufferSize / 2);

  // newVec.shrink_to_fit();
  std::cout<<"Capacity after resize: "<<newVec.capacity()<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0

Comment: `std::vector::resize()` should _not_ reduce the capacity.  See:  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize

Comment: @StoryTeller It seems that this is true. But it it possible to configure when this is going to happen?

Comment: @imoutidi - Not really. It must happen when the capacity is reached, of course. But vectors aren't supposed to *lose* capacity very easily.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes you are right. As Chad commented the reference says "Vector capacity is never reduced when resizing to smaller size because that would invalidate all iterators, rather than only the ones that would be invalidated by the equivalent sequence of pop_back() calls. " As Peter answered the problem is that the iterator is a copy. Applying Peters solution solved my problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When creating a copy of a vector, the copy will have the same size but not necessarily the same capacity as the original.

In your loops of the form

```
for(auto itr : rvec1)
```

`itr` will be a copy of elements of `rvec1`.   To obtain references to the actual elements use

```
for(auto &itr : rvec1)
```

or

```
for(const auto &itr : rvec1)
```

Comment: or `auto&&`, which just works everywhere and never makes needless copies.

Comment: @Yakk  Just to clarify, `auto&&` can't be used when you need to mutate the container elements can it?

Comment: @MarkB Define "can't be used".  It doesn't guarantee the container elements are mutable through it.  But if they are mutable, it would work.  In addition, if you have a vector of bool, only `auto&&` is going to work (and it will permit mutation).

Comment: Yes, `auto &&` is an alternative.   I prefer code to be explicit that the loop is working with a `const` reference though - although I admit that is a stylistic preference.   I also tend to prefer avoiding using `std::vector<bool>` (which means I don't have that motivation to use `auto &&`) since it doesn't provide all capabilities of `std::vector` - I don't generally need to optimisations it provides.

Comment: @peter `for(auto&& e:range( input_iterator(file) ))` -- any `input_iterator` can return a proxy reference or a value as well!  And an `input_iterator` that permits writing back to elements is useful for filter ranges.